# Selenium: Page JS not running, stuck in load

Tags: selenium

Running a **scraper** on a site and the js doesn't seem to be working. Stuck on "loading" on the page but the rest of the html is loading fine.

Screen shot of load.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WofB.png

```
from selenium import webdriver

bin_path = ''#path to local bin file for driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=bin_path,desired_capabilities={'javascriptEnabled': True})
driver.get(URL)
```

Not sure if I need to pull the name of each script and execute it one at a time?

Comment: seems like I need to explicitly run the scripts in the <script> brackets? I think since there's a link to the script src the WebDriver must not be running it implicitly on the page even if I'm enabling 'javascriptEnabled'?

Comment: So it seems like the WebDriver isn't able to load some of the externally linked java scripts. I am see 403 error in the JS console.